# How to start manually-installed OpenSSH, and run at boot

Tags: ssh, startup, services, reboot, openssh

I've manually built an older version of OpenSSH with make + make install, for educational purposes.
Is it possible to start it with `sudo systemctl restart ssh`, as when we install OpenSSH from apt-get?
Moreover, how can we configure this manually-built OpenSSH to run at boot time, every time the server starts?

Comment: Usually, you just need to `make install` to install everything, but here I don't think that sshd provides a service file. You certainly need to create the service file yourself (for instance NixOs does it here https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/services/networking/ssh/sshd.nix#L458).

Comment: And to create your service, you can get inspired for instance from this https://www.shubhamdipt.com/blog/how-to-create-a-systemd-service-in-linux/. For the options, you can get inspired either by the one used in your distribution, or get inspired by the one of nixos linked above.

Comment: AFAIK the default service file is `/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service`, however you shouldn't modify it directly. The systemd manpage suggests using `/usr/local/lib/systemd/system`.

Comment: The service `sshd`must be enabled, since you want the service, not the client (which is ssh)